# How to insert Value from textBox to dataGridView in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm having a problem in passing a value from `TextBox` to `DataGridView`. After I click the button, there's an error will pop out saying that

> Index was out of Range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name index.

The database I use is Navicat for MySQL because for me it's easy to use.

Here's the code i use:

```
private void PassDataGrid()
{
    double a, b;
    bool isAvalid = double.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out a);
    bool isBvalid = double.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out b);
    if (isAvalid && isBvalid)
    {
        textBox6.Text = (a * b).ToString();
    }
    dt.Rows.Add(textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text, textBox4.Text, textBox5.Text, textBox6.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    total();
}
```

Here's code to add column's in `DataGridView`:

```
private void POS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductNo", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("quantity", typeof(decimal));
    dt.Columns.Add("price", typeof(decimal));
    dt.Columns.Add("Subtotal", typeof(decimal));

    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}
```

Comment: You are inserting `strings` where the datagrid expects `decimal`, convert the text to decimal first. I'm not sure if that's the cause of the error, but surely it's wrong.

Comment: when you use the debugger to step through the code which line is it throwing the error..? also where are you declaring the DataTable variable `dt` also read up on how to do proper data conversion when assigning to your datatable column types

Comment: @MethodMan I already Declare DataTable dt = new DataTable(); under my Class method, But the error is still there. And I  always use a debugger.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing error? what is total () in the code?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya don't mind the total(); it's just calling another method.

Comment: Did you try debugging ans see Which line of code is giving error?

Comment: I think total(); gave the error. You might calculate the SubTotals.